# $k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/Q$ is UFD for non-singular quadratic form $Q$ and $n\ge 5$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, quadratic-forms, unique-factorization-domains

I am looking for a reference for the following result. Thanks in advance.

> Let $k$ be a field of any characteristic other than $2$.
> Klein and Nagata showed that the ring $R:=k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/Q$ is a UFD
> whenever $Q$ is a non-singular quadratic form in the $X$'s and $n$ is
> at least $5$.

Comment: I am not sure this counts as a reference, but this is Exercise II.6.5 in Hartshorne's book. The proof indicated by Hartshorne is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

A proof can be found for example in theorem 8.2 of [http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr30.pdf](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/%7Epubl/ln/tifr30.pdf)

Another elementary proof can be found in the algebra II textbook (in German) by Scheja and Storch as theorem 60.12, see https://books.google.de/books?id=UKrivyLPeuMC&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181&dq=Klein%E2%80%93Nagata&source=bl&ots=LNQtqsQ93w&sig=ACfU3U15WjK6NNytTVAycYtg4-DvSzmK5Q&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwie7Jac2_byAhUWhv0HHWFGA3MQ6AF6BAgTEAM#v=onepage&q=Klein%E2%80%93Nagata&f=false